# How to find jira issues with componets lead by the current user?

Tags: jira, jql

I tried to use the following jql but it resulted in jql validation error:

component in componentsLeadByUser( currentUser() )

Error in the JQL Query: Expecting ')' or ',' but got '('.

When I replace the currentUser() with concrete user names, it works well. but i would like to create an universal filter for all users for a shared dashboard.

Could you please help me with this question？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation ["Advanced Searching Functions"](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AOD/Advanced+Searching+Functions#AdvancedSearchingFunctions-componentsLeadByUser%28%29)

> You can optionally specify a user, or if the user is omitted the current user (i.e. you) will be used.

Therefore *to find jira issues with componets lead by the current user:*

`component in componentsLeadByUser()`